# how to direct a user in my app to ad b2c change password policy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I have added the change password policy as directed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

How can I now direct the user when they click the "Change Password" link in my app to direct them to this policy?

I am trying this below but doesn't seem to work (Globals.EditProfilePolicyId is my change password profile's policy id):

```
public void ChangePassword()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri }, Globals.EditProfilePolicyId);
}
```

I keep getting this browser popup to enter credentials even though I'm logged in.:
[image]

After debugging it a bit and looking at some other samples, the policy that is last specified in ConfigureAuth, is the only one that has any effect.

Below is the code:

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Required for Azure webapps, as by default they force TLS 1.2 and this project attempts 1.0
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
        CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
    });
               
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.EditProfilePolicyId));
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.ResetPasswordPolicyId));
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.DefaultPolicy));
}

private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
{
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
        MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, policy),

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
        RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,

        // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        },

        // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            SaveSigninToken = true //save the token in the bootstrap context
        },

        // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
        Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {Globals.ReadTasksScope} {Globals.WriteTasksScope}",
        ResponseType = "id_token",
        // ASP.NET web host compatible cookie manager
        CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
    };
}

/*
 *  On each call to Azure AD B2C, check if a policy (e.g. the profile edit or password reset policy) has been specified in the OWIN context.
 *  If so, use that policy when making the call. Also, don't request a code (since it won't be needed).
 */
private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy) && !policy.Equals(Globals.DefaultPolicy))
    {
        notification.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
        notification.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
        notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(Globals.DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

/*
 * Catch any failures received by the authentication middleware and handle appropriately
 */
private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    notification.HandleResponse();

    // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page
    // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
    if (notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
    {
        // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
        notification.Response.Redirect("/User/ResetPassword2");
    }
    else if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
    {
        notification.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

In the above code if I call `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.EditProfilePolicyId))` last, then when loading the app and going to /user/sign in, it will actually go through the "Change Password" policy that I have configured it for.

If I call `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(Globals.ResetPasswordPolicyId));` last, then it will take me through reset password policy when launching the app.

Comment: That’s all you should need to do. The screenshot shows it did not even hit AAD B2C endpoint. Can you trace your code to see what it’s executing to show this login pop up?

Comment: When I trace it, it just goes through the ResetPassword2() method twice and then the page is loaded with that popup. I've updated my post with more details and code.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT anything else I can check that would impact the behaviour? Would something in one of the policies prevent it from hitting the B2c endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured it out. I changed my handler in the controller to the following:

```
public void ChangePassword()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Let the middleware know you are trying to use the reset password policy (see OnRedirectToIdentityProvider in Startup.Auth.cs)
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Set("Policy", Globals.EditProfilePolicyId);

        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
    }
}
```

In the above, make sure you DO NOT specify the policy as the second parameter to the `Authentication.Challenge()` method like I was doing.

Also make sure that in Startup.Auth.cs, you only inject the OpenId Auth middleware once - for the default policy. e.g. the SUSI policy. Basically [follow this Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) exactly. You will see that `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` is only being called once - with the default signin policy. You do not need to call it for other policies here. The controller handler will assign a "policy" to owin context, and redirect it to the identity provider and will trigger the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` delegate specified in the Startup.Auth.cs which will then check the "policy" in the owin context, and replace the default policy with the new one and redirect to this policy accordingly.

Comment: hi Riz, i couldnt find any sample where ChangePassword flow is being called, could you please point me to a sample if any