# Forgot Password policy redirect

Tags: .net, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to integrate a .NET app with Azure AD B2C using https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi.

Integration has been successful but I am facing an issue with the Forgot Password flow. The code redirects to the 'Change Password' policy that is invoked post login. For me, Forgot Password and Change Password policies are different. On the exception, I want to redirect to a different policy and not '/Account/ResetPassword' which invokes Change Password policy.

How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Any pointers please.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a reset password policy and change the code in the controller to use this policy.

```
<add key="ida:ResetPasswordPolicyId" value="b2c_1_reset" />
```

**Update**

"Change Password" is not one of the out-of-the-box ones but you can add it as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394509/how-to-direct-a-user-in-my-app-to-ad-b2c-change-password-policy).

Comment: The problem is ChangePwd and ForgotPwd is pointing to the same policy in the application code. For me, the logic is different so can't point to a single policy. What app side code changes are needed to point ForgotPwd to a separate policy?

Comment: Are you using built-in policies or custom policies?

Comment: Custom policies.